# Span of the trivial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering is the span of the trivial vector space the {0} vector in $\Bbb R^2$ for example just 1 vector $(0,0)$ or can it be any vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ since we can pick $t \in\Bbb R$ to be zero so in this case there infinite spanning vectors ?

Comment: The span of _any_ vector subspace is the subspace itself. So the span of $\{0\}$ is $\{0\}$. Span is only an interesting operation for subsets (like finite sets of vectors) that are not already subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of describing the span of a given set is the intersection of all subspaces of a given vector space containing said set; because all subspaces spaces contain the empty set, we need to take the intersection of all subspaces.  Every subspace contains zero (this is an axiom), so their intersection is Span$(\emptyset)=0$.

EDIT:  Replace "empty set" with "zero vector" and "$\emptyset$" with "$0$", to be consistent with what was asked, otherwise the ideas don't change.

Comment: Look at the first line under "definition" here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span

Comment: The question was not about the span of the empty set, but about the span of the subspace formed of the zero vector only. Those spans are the same, but the two problems should not be confused.

Comment: I was confused at first because I thought that $\emptyset$ was the trivial vector space; but of course, this is nonsense, because every vector space must contain an additive identity.

Answer (score 5):

The span of a set of vectors $K$ in a vector space $V$ is the collection of linear combinations of them, which means finite sums $a_1v_1+...+a_rv_r$ where the $a_k$ are any scalars and each $v_k \in K.$ For your question $K$ is the set $\{0\}$ having only one vector in it, so the "sums" just mentioned have only one term $a_1v_1$ where $v_1=0,$ the zero vector of $V.$ One of the definitions of scalar multiplication of a scalar by a vector says that if the vector is $v=0$ then $a_1v=0,$ i.e. again the zero vector. So in this case there are no other vectors in the span than the zero vector. (You can't "reach" other vectors in $V$ by multiplying the zero vector by a scalar, for the reason just mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it just 1 vector since The 0 vector has no basis so it can't be expressed as linear combination of independent vectors, so by that fact the vectors that can represent it is only itself.

Comment: The span of the set $\{ o \}$ is the subspace $\{ o \}$ itself. The vector "list" $\{ o \}$ is not a basis because it is linearly dependent. A dependence relation is, e.g., $1o=0$. Instead, the basis for $\{ o \}$ is the empty set $\{  \} = \varnothing$. Linear combinations are empty, in particular all coefficients are $0$ as required. It follows that the dimension of $\{ o \}$ is $| \varnothing | = 0$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen This is mostly just a curiosity, but over the zero ring, any module has just the zero vector in it, and so on the surface looks a lot like this case. However, in this space both $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ are bases for the space, and this is up to isomorphism the unique example of a basis being a proper subset of another basis.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I suppose you are right, but as soon as we go to modules, other "bad" thing can happen, like no bases exist, or two bases have different cardinality, etc. However with vector spaces (over a field) a basis always exists and has a unique cardinality.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I know, I just wanted to point this out because this is about the only case when you have such a failure of the usual behavior you expect from vector spaces in going to modules. Different cardinalities? Sure. But surely at least proper subsets are respected by bases in modules, and it turns out that they *almost* do, except for this one case, which makes it interesting.

Comment: This is a very confused sentence. The subspace $\{0\}$ does have a basis, which is the empty set; the set of linear combinations of the empty set is $\{0\}$, because there is always the empty linear combination (with $0$ terms), even of the empty set of vectors, and the value of this linear combination is the zero vector. But the question OP asked does not involve any bases at all!